# Attempted to load class "Month" from namespace "DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I get the error `Attempted to load class "Month" from namespace "DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace` when i'm trying to create a query that fetch data by year and month

Inside my repository

```
 public function getCongePris($mois,$annee,$matricule)
    {
        $emConfig = $this->_em->getConfiguration();
        $emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('YEAR', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year');
        $emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('MONTH', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month');

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('co')->leftJoin('co.personnel','p');
        $qb->select('co')
            ->where('p.matricule= :matricule')->andWhere('co.statutDemande=:statut ')
            ->andWhere('MONTH( co.debutConge)=:mois')->andWhere('YEAR(co.debutConge)=:annee');

        $qb->setParameter('annee',$annee)->setParameter('mois',$mois)->setParameter('matricule',$matricule)->setParameter('statut','ACCEPTE');

        $conges = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
        return $conges;
    }
```

Inside my config.yml

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
        dql:
            string_functions:
                MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

Comment: Are you sure your `Month` and `Year` classes are located inside `DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql` namespace?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your Symfony cache?

Comment: I can't find the DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql anywhere

Comment: And yes, i've already clear my symfony cache

Comment: And... If you can't find it anywhere, why did you use it in your Doctrine?

Comment: well, i've tried to follow tutorials and i didn't notice that, sorry... Now it works, i've installed the beberlei/Doctrine Extensions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must install extension which will add required class to the Symfony.

This bundle should do the job: https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

```
composer require beberlei/DoctrineExtensions
```